# how to disable the default theme or animation applied to wpf application in windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have developed a WPF application to run on Windows 7 and Windows 8. All the styles I applied seem to work fine when the application runs on Windows 8 but when the application runs on Windows 7, the default OS theme seems to get applied to my application:

1. the buttons after clicking get a breathing effect
2. the progress bar gets a glassy effect

Is there a way for me to disable these features?

Comment: Take a look at the [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx#styling_themes) page on MSDN.